# Where should I put the logic in Laravel to untangle a request and update the models?

Tags: php, laravel, service

I have a question about where to put the logic for updating related models in Laravel.

I have a model for relative dates that depend either on a fixed date (milestone) or on another relative date. There are now several models in my application that contain such a relative date.

If I query such a relative date I get the desired result. But now I don't know where / how to place the logic to save or update it.

A request has the following structure:

```php
array (
  'id' => NULL, // Or id if it already exists
  'difference' => 71,
  'fixed' => NULL, // Date string if a fixed date is selected
  'parent' => NULL, // An array of this format if it depends on another relative date
  'milestone' => // Dependency on milestone
  array (
    'id' => 1, // This id is needed as mileston_id in the db afterwards
    'name' => 'Test',
    'pit' => '2019-11-01',
  ),
)
```

Now i would need some logic to extract the needed data (In this case: `id, difference, milestone_id`) and create or update the RelativeDate model and return the id. Then this id or model could be referenced in the 'parent' model.

I don't want to do that in the controller of each model, as there would be a lot of code duplication. And as far as I know it's not possible to properly inject a controller (RelativeDateController) in another controller? (Which was my second idea)

I thought about some kind of service that gets the relative date array and does all the logic and model mapping regarding the relative date. Then i could inject this service in all models, which hold such a relativ date?

Would that be the right way to go, or would you even suggest another solution?

As additional information I added the migration and the model definition below.

---

**Migration (Relative Date)**

```php
Schema::create('relative_dates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('difference')->nullable(); // Difference to parent date in days
    $table->integer('milestone_id')->nullable()->unsigned(); // Relation to milestone or null
    $table->date('fixed')->nullable(); // Fixed date
    $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable()->unsigned(); // Relation to another relative date or null

    $table->foreign('milestone_id')->references('id')->on('milestones')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('relative_dates')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
});
```

**Model (Relative Date)**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class RelativeDate extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['relative_date'];

    public function getRelativeDateAttribute()
    {
        if ( $this->fixed !== null ) {
            return Carbon::instance($this->fixed);
        } else if($this->milestone_id !== null) {
            $mpit = Carbon::instance($this->milestone->pit);
            return $mpit->addDays($this->difference);
        } else if( $this->parent_id !== null ) {
            $parent = $this->parent->relative_date;
            return $parent->addDays($this->difference);
        }
    }

    public function milestone(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Milestone', 'milestone_id', 'id');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RelativeDate', 'parent_id', 'id')->with('parent', 'milestone');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Julien Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563021/julien-gabriel) suggested I tried to solve it with a trait and it worked fine. For completion this is my solution:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\RelativeDate as RelativeDateModel;

trait RelativeDate
{

    public function updateOrCreate($data)
    {
        if ($data['fixed'] != null) {
            $newData = array(
                'difference' => null,
                'fixed' => $data['fixed'],
                'parent_id' => null,
                'milestone_id' => null,
            );
        } elseif ( $data['milestone'] != null ) {
            $newData = array(
                'difference' => $data['difference'],
                'fixed' => null,
                'parent_id' => null,
                'milestone_id' => $data['milestone']['id'],
            );
        } elseif ( $data['parent'] != null ) {
            $newData = array(
                'difference' => $data['difference'],
                'fixed' => null,
                'parent_id' => $data['parent']['id'],
                'milestone_id' => null,
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        if ( $data['id'] != null ) {
            $rd = RelativeDateModel::find($data['id']);
            if ( $rd->update($newData) ) {
                return $rd->id;
            }
        } else {
            $rd = RelativeDateModel::create($newData);
            return $rd->id;
        }
    }
}
```